# How can I get the count of a capture group then replace the characters with a specific character?

Tags: regex, capture-group

How can I get the count of a capture group and replace it with the same number of characters that I specify?

For example here is a string...

`123456789ABCD00001DDD`

My regex with capture groups is as follows...

`^([123456789]{9})([ABCD]{1,4})([0]{1,5})([0-9]{1,5})([D]*)$`

When I use something like Notepad++ I want to find the above and replace it with something like...

`\1\2   \4\5`

Making the end results look like...

`123456789ABCD   1DDD`

Example located at https://regex101.com/r/fykEnn/1

Comment: What is the logic behind this replacement, and also what is wrong with your current pattern, which looks at a glance to be correct?

Comment: Sorry @TimBiegeleisen, what I have above will work for that exact instance.  But the  5 characters `00001` are always changing so they could be any CHARACTER (0-9, A-Z).  I need to somehow count the zeros so I can replace them with the same number of SPACES.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex with `\G` and a positive lookahead:

```
(?:^([1-9]{9}[ABCD]{1,4})(?=0{1,5}\d{1,5}D*$)|\G)0
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fykEnn/2)

`\G` asserts position at the end of the previous match or the start of the string for the first match.

Comment: Interesting.  I'm looking at this now to see if it's what I'm after.  I never even knew about the Substitution area at the bottom of regex101 LOL - Thanks!

Comment: OK I think this will work for me but I'm running into a little issue with my data in my test string.  I completely forgot I needed to make sure that the 5 characters ex: `00001` or `00A1A` gets turned into 4 characters ex: `   1` and ` A1A`.  New Example based off yours https://regex101.com/r/fykEnn/3.  Is there a way to limit that capture group to only dhow 4 of the 5 characters in the end?

Comment: Sorry new requirement is not clear to me. Can you edit the question with few more examples and clarify.

Comment: Never mind, I figured out a quick and dirty way of getting rid of the FIRST zero, just used another capture group then did not use that capture group in the substitution.  Accepted your answer, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

In `bash`, using `sed`:

```sh
$ echo 123456789ABCD00001DDD | sed -re 's/([123456789]{9})([ABCD]{1,4})([0]{1,5})([0-9]{1,5})([D]*)$/\1\2   \4\5 /g'
123456789ABCD   1DDD
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should to use both lookbehind & lookahead assertion with a single digit ...
example ...

Find what: `(?<=[A-Z])\d{4}(?=\d[A-Z])`
Replace with: `a space`